# Android Chat Q-MunicatoreError:Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.8.1

Tags: android

I want to make a chat application for chat with own group persons. when I Integrate Q-Municater, I got following errors:

> Android Chat Q-MunicatoreError:Failed to resolve:
>   com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.8.1

Comment: you didnt add any errors?

Comment: Please go through once. [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: as error says, compiler didn't find the library `com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.8.1`. You have to fix it. Problem is somewhere in sources.

Answer (score 0):

The library you use is using the old version of [material-dialog](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) library. So you need to rebuild your library using the latest version of material-dialog.

Read more the issue that related with your problem: [Library not sync](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/739).